# DynamicObject - invoking method based on argument value

Tags: c#, dynamicobject

I'd like to be able to store a dictionary of Actions and being able to invoke those based on key for the dictionary. If key is not found, then no action is getting invoked. I had an idea of performing invocation using an object that extends DynamicObject and get dictionary of actions at construction time, but then all examples of how to use DynamicObject are based on properties, not methods. 
I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
`dynamicDictionary.InvokeMethod(commandName);`
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The opensource framework [Dynamitey](https://github.com/ekonbenefits/dynamitey) will do this. For a Dictionary of actions you can either construct using an MS built-in `ExpandoObject` or `Dynamitey` has an `DynamicObjects.BaseDictionary` that will work like a proxy to a dictionary.

If you fill either with actions as properties they can be invoked as methods. If you need to invoke them by a string name, you can use `Dynamic.InvokeAction(dynamicDictionary, commandName)`. This uses the DLR to invoke a method it's faster than reflection on Static objects and make it's possible on Dynamic Objects.

Comment: Is there a way to setup a default action, so that when a requested actions is not found, default would kick in?

Comment: @Sean just subclass `ImpromptuDictionary and override `TryInvokeMember` then you can call the base implementation and if it returns false do your default action and return true.